# What happens to existing installed Apps if I edit InHouse Distribution profile?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-app-group, enterprise-distribution, apple-developer

I have made an iPad In-House Distribution App which is installed in 2000 iPads of my company. Now, I want to enable `App group` to share few data between my Apps of same developer account. For that, I will have to enable `App Groups` for my App id and re-generate `Development` and `Distribution` profiles.

If I do that, will it affect existing installed Apps? Will it affect upcoming releases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer to your query:

> Change in provisioning profile won't effect on existing enterprise app, installed in user devices.

An enterprise app gets affected only, if you make any change (revoke/renew/regenerate) in your distribution certificate.

Comment: Will it affect existing live apps if we edit entitlements in AppID?